# Is there a decent Java client for the Tumblr API?

Tags: java, tumblr

I googled a bit, but all java clients for the tumblr API were outdated, poorly written, not supported, etc.

Is there something that is up-to-date, is of sufficient quality, and (optionally) has a maven dependency? Something like twitter4j, but for tumblr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jumblr is the official Java API for Tumblr, here is [a link](https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr/)! And here is the [documentation](http://tumblr.github.io/jumblr/javadoc/)

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to also use Spring Social, I've written a Tumblr client for it here:

https://github.com/sdouglass/spring-social-tumblr

Spring Social is a great, solid library for building and using OAuth 1/2 API clients. Using it gives you the ability to just drop in support for a variety of other APIs very easily.

http://www.springsource.org/spring-social

I've included info for adding spring-social-tumbler as a Maven dependency in the README for the project, which you can see at first the link above.

I think if you want to use it, the simplest approach would be something like:

```
Tumblr tumblr = new TumblrTemplate(yourTumblrApiKey);
```

If you want to access the API on behalf of a user, you'd need to use OAuth to get an access token and access token secret for the user, at which point you could do something like:

```
Tumblr tumblr = new TumblrTemplate(yourTumblrAppConsumerKey, yourTumblrAppSecret, userAccessToken, userAccessTokenSecret);
```

If you integrate Spring Social into your project it can help with building appropriately authorized Tumblr instances, obtaining and storing access tokens/secrets for users, etc. You'll have to check their docs for more info about that. My code is designed to "plug in" to a typical Spring Social setup the same way as the official libraries like Spring Social Facebook, Spring Social Twitter, etc.

Comment: I've added a 1.0-SNAPSHOT release to a Maven repo I keep on GitHub: https://github.com/sdouglass/sdouglass-maven-repo

Comment: Sorry, how can I integrate it in my Spring web app?

Comment: Add the following to your pom.xml (assuming you are using Maven):

    <repositories>  
        <repository>  
            <id>sdouglass-snapshots</id>  
            <url>https://raw.github.com/sdouglass/sdouglass-maven-repo/master/snapshots</url>  
        </repository>  
    </repositories>  
    ...  
    <dependency>  
        <group>org.springframework.social</group>  
        <artifact>spring-social-tumblr</artifact>  
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
     </dependency>

Comment: I've tried to update my answer with more details, hope that helps.

Comment: @sddouglass Your repository doesn't seem to work any longer. Is it still advised to use your tumblr API with the latest Spring / will it work? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't been actively using or developing my library unfortunately. Tumblr later released an official Java client called "Jumblr" as mentioned by Peter T and Saf. You may have better luck starting with that and writing a thin wrapper/adapter around it to make it work with Spring Social.

Answer (score 1):

You may also have a look at Temboo. Temboo offers streamlined and normalized access to many APIs, including Tumblr, via a native Java SDK.

My personal favorite reasons for using this library is how easy it makes OAuth and that Temboo lets me save API credentials in the cloud so I don't have to go through the hoops of abstracting them from my code or securing it on my machines.

You can check it out and play with it at http://temboo.com/library/Library/Tumblr

I should also note that I work at Temboo. So when you check it out, if you have any questions, feel free to message me.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [Webshell](http://webshell.io).

They provide a simple REST API that can be used to call third party APIs. Among those apis, there is the tumblr API.

Don't forget to check out their hilarious blog : http://apijoy.tumblr.com/ :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Jumblr](https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr) library. It is very easy and powerful.